# Cursor for loop - help? Dont understand

Tags: plsql

I do not understand where employeeRec comes from? Is this like an advance for loop in java where employeeRec  acts as a item looping through employeeCur

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

`employeeRec` is called the *loop index* and it is implicitly declared as a %ROWTYPE record variable that matches the type of the cursor `employeeCur`.

If it wasn't the cursor FOR loop, you'd first declare a cursor, and then a cursor variable, open the cursor, fetch, take care when to exit the loop, close the cursor, such as

```
declare
  cursor employeeCur is 
    select empid, ...;
  employeeRec employeeCur%rowtype;          --> this
begin
  open employeeCur;
  loop
    fetch employeeCur into employeeRec;     --> this
    exit when employeeCur%notfound;
    update employee set ...
  end loop;
  close employeeCur;
end;
```

As you can see, cursor FOR loop is easier to write and maintain because Oracle does a lot of tasks for you.